# A site for vote math book

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

My question:

Is there a site like **[www.imdb.com](http://www.imdb.com)** for mathematical book whick can vote users 
to all published math books from major publisher, like springer, cambridge, dover, oxford, siam, ...?

When I want read a specific topic in math, I found many book with same name or same topic and hard to picks one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try Amazon books and sort the search results by user ratings.

Comment: @quasi has a good idea!